# Does setting state work with the useNavigate hook in React with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-typescript

When a user submits a form with an image upload, they are redirected to an "uploading" route while they wait for the server. If there is an error, they should be directed back to the main page with the error message showing at the bottom. However, the error state is not being set; it just remains an empty string. I'm not sure if this has to do with useNavigate because the state is being set when the user is on a different page. Here is my code:

```tsx
function ImageForm() {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState<Blob>();
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // react-router-dom

  const handleSubmit = async (event: FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    if (!image) return setError("Please upload an image file.");
    formData.append("image", image);
    navigate("/upload");
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/images", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
      });
      const json: Image | { error: string } = await response.json();
      // None of these setError calls are affecting the error state
      if ("error" in json) {
        navigate("/");
        setError(json.error);
      } else {
        navigate(`/${json._id}`);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      navigate("/");
      setError(e instanceof Error ? e.message : "Please try again.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        encType="multipart/form-data"
        className="upload--form"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <input
          type="file"
          name="image"
          accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
          onChange={handleUpload} // sets image state to the uploaded file
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
      {error && <div className="error">{error}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried calling setError as shown above. I also tried converting the async/await to .then syntax. Finally, I tried using a combination of `useRef` and `useEffect`. Whenever the `errorRef` variable was updated, an effect was supposed to run and call `setError(errorRef.current)`. None of these methods updated the error state successfully.

Comment: We'll need to see your `<Route>`'s to know whether ImageForm remains mounted when you do the navigation. If it unmounts, then setting state won't do anything of note because it's no longer on the page.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that the upload route had to be a child of /. This solved the problem! 