# Variable is turning to undefined when I pass it in as a prop to another .js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created my app file which turns an `isAuthenticated` variable to true on a successful login connection. I have verified that the Firebase API call is working correctly as only upon entry of a valid username and password does my program shift to the /admin page.

I want my header bar to hide the login button after a successful login but it is not working as my `isAuthenticated` variable turns to undefined once I pass it in instead of turning to `true`. I know this is happening because I am putting a console.log statement in my header file to print out the value of the `isAuthenticated` variable. In my `Header.js` file, I want to use this variable to control whether or not the login button appears.

This is my code for the `App.js` and `Header.js` files:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Header';  
import LoginForm from './LoginForm'; 
import AdminPage from './AdminPage'; 

import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
   //
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

function HomePage() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const auth = getAuth();
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        navigate('/admin');
      } else {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [auth, navigate]);

  const handleLogin = async (username, password) => {
    try {
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, username, password);
      console.log('Login successful');
      navigate('/admin'); // Navigate to the admin page on successful login
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Header
            isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
            handleLoginFormSubmit={handleLogin} // Pass handleLogin as a prop
        />
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/admin" element={<AdminPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

function Header({ isAuthenticated, handleLoginFormSubmit }) {
  const [showLoginForm, setShowLoginForm] = useState(false);

  const handleLoginButtonClick = () => {
    setShowLoginForm(true);
  };

  return (
    <header className="App-header">
      <h1 className="App-title">Family Wordle</h1>
      {isAuthenticated ? null : (
        <>
          {!showLoginForm ? (
            <button className="App-button" onClick={handleLoginButtonClick}>
              Admin Login
            </button>
          ) : (
            <LoginForm handleLogin={handleLoginFormSubmit} /> // Updated prop name
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: If your component unmounts during the `navigate()` call, then you will lose the component state. I'm not sure how `useNavigate` works, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75229477/4476484) and its comments might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your route at `/admin` renders the `AdminPage` component. This is a different component from your `HomePage` component. When you call `navigate('/admin')`, your `HomePage` component will unmount, thus deleting all of its state. Since you keep the `isAuthenticated` value in the state of your `HomePage` component, that state is lost when you nagivate away and the component unmounts.

You didn't show the code for your `AdminPage` component, but I'm guessing it also renders a `Header` as one of its children. So it appears to be the same header to you, but it's actually a new component.

---

If you want to verify when exactly your components are mounting and unmounting, you can add the following code:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Mounted');
        return () => {
            console.log('Unmounted');
        };
    }, []);

    ...
};
```

This will print `'Mounted'` when `MyComponent` mounts and `'Unmounted'` when it unmounts. If you try this in your case, you should see that the `HomePage` component is unmounting when you call `navigate('/admin')`.